# Can I ever dive into the river with my Wetsuit?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In **Animal Crossing: New Leaf,** I know that you can swim in the ocean when you have your *Wetsuit* on. However, when I try to dive in the *river*, my character just **moves his arms in a way that he's pretending to swim.** Is there any other way to get in? Maybe a glitch or hack? Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't dive into the river. However, by using the Tweeter/Beans glitch (or the King Tut glitch), it is possible to stand on the river (which makes fishing a lot easier!).

You need two people to do the glitch.

1. Blow on your tweeter/use the Setsubun beans.
2. Have someone constantly push you from behind into the river.
3. Repeat until you're in the river :-)

Comment: and... How do you get a tweeter or beans?

Comment: You can get a tweeter by StreetPassing somebody 10 times. Isabelle also hands them out at New Year's eve if you talk to her twice. The beans are unobtainable in the European and US version of the game. You'll either need to visit somebody during the [Setsubun/Bean Throwing Festival](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Bean_Throwing_Festival) or find someone to dupe it for you via the [duping trick/glitch](http://kotaku.com/this-animal-crossing-new-leaf-glitch-lets-you-duplicat-792173481).

Comment: The link doesn't say when the bean throwing festival is.

Comment: Yes it does, the event is being held on February 3rd ;-)

Comment: oh, okay! So if I change the date to February 3rd, the Bean-Throwing Festival will be taking place?

Comment: The event is Japan-exclusive which means that it won't be held on EU/USA version of the game. If you have a Japanese copy of the game (and a Japanese 3DS), yes. If not, the only way is to visit somebody next February or by having somebody dupe the beans for you. However, getting the tweeter is much easier imo, as you only have to StreetPass somebody 10 times. Would probably take much less time than obtaining (the) beans.

Comment: Do you have the beans?